# avr-gdb connected, but there is no prompt

Tags: linux, gdb, avr

avr-gdb connects,but there is no prompt. Pressing ^C I get a prompt and now gdb accepts commands.
However I do not know how got to this point and what was done to get there.Here is what I do:

**steve@Apa:~/projects/avr/testburst$ make**

```
/usr/bin/avr-gcc -D F_CPU=8000000 -I.  -ggdb -mmcu=attiny45 -Os -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -gdwarf-2 -std=gnu99 -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-ahlms=testburst.lst -c testburst.c -o testburst.o
/usr/bin/avr-gcc -D F_CPU=8000000 -Wl,--no-undefined,-Map,testburst.out.map -mmcu=attiny45 -L  -lm  -o testburst.out testburst.o
```

***Flash program and enable debugwire:***

**steve@Apa:~/projects/avr/testburst$ make dwflash**

> /usr/bin/avr-objcopy -j .text                    \    -j .data
> \     -O ihex testburst.out testburst.hex /usr/bin/avrdude -F -c jtag2isp
> -P usb -B 10 -b 115200 -p t45 -e -U flash:w:testburst.hex -U lfuse:w:0x62:m -U hfuse:w:0x9f:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m avrdude:
> jtagmkII_setparm(): bad response to set parameter command: RSP_FAILED
> avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): ISP activation failed, trying debugWire
> avrdude: Target prepared for ISP, signed off. avrdude: Now retrying
> without power-cycling the target.
>
> avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
>
> Reading | ################################################## | 100%
> 0.02s
>
> avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9206 (probably t45) avrdude: erasing
> chip avrdude: reading input file "testburst.hex" avrdude: input file
> testburst.hex auto detected as Intel Hex avrdude: writing flash (482
> bytes):
>
> Writing | ################################################## | 100%
> 0.30s
>
> avrdude: 482 bytes of flash written avrdude: verifying flash memory
> against testburst.hex: avrdude: load data flash data from input file
> testburst.hex: avrdude: input file testburst.hex auto detected as
> Intel Hex avrdude: input file testburst.hex contains 482 bytes
> avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:
>
> Reading | ################################################## | 100%
> 0.31s
>
> avrdude: verifying ... avrdude: 482 bytes of flash verified avrdude:
> reading input file "0x62" avrdude: writing lfuse (1 bytes):
>
> Writing | ################################################## | 100%
> 0.02s
>
> avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse written avrdude: verifying lfuse memory
> against 0x62: avrdude: load data lfuse data from input file 0x62:
> avrdude: input file 0x62 contains 1 bytes avrdude: reading on-chip
> lfuse data:
>
> Reading | ################################################## | 100%
> 0.01s
>
> avrdude: verifying ... avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified avrdude:
> reading input file "0x9f" avrdude: writing hfuse (1 bytes):
>
> Writing | ################################################## | 100%
> 0.02s
>
> avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse written avrdude: verifying hfuse memory
> against 0x9f: avrdude: load data hfuse data from input file 0x9f:
> avrdude: input file 0x9f contains 1 bytes avrdude: reading on-chip
> hfuse data:
>
> Reading | ################################################## | 100%
> 0.01s
>
> avrdude: verifying ... avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse verified avrdude:
> reading input file "0xff" avrdude: writing efuse (1 bytes):
>
> Writing | ################################################## | 100%
> 0.02s
>
> avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse written avrdude: verifying efuse memory
> against 0xff: avrdude: load data efuse data from input file 0xff:
> avrdude: input file 0xff contains 1 bytes avrdude: reading on-chip
> efuse data:
>
> Reading | ################################################## | 100%
> 0.01s
>
> avrdude: verifying ... avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse verified
>
> avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:9F, L:62)
>
> avrdude done.  Thank you.

***Trying debug***

**steve@Apa:~/projects/avr/testburst$ avarice -w -P attiny45 --jtag usb:24cf  --mkII :4242 &**

> AVaRICE version 2.14, Sep 17 2020 16:15:33
>
> JTAG config starting. Found a device: JTAGICEmkII Serial number:
> 00:b0:00:00:24:cf Reported debugWire device ID: 0x9206 Configured for
> device ID: 0x9206 attiny45 -- Matched with attiny45 JTAG config
> complete. Preparing the target device for On Chip Debugging. Waiting
> for connection on port 4242.

***I start avr-gdb in a new terminal
The gdbinit content is_as follows:***
*target remote localhost:4242
break main
continue*

**steve@Apa:~/projects/avr/testburst$ avr-gdb testburst.out -x gdbinit**

> GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1.90.20210103-git Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software
> Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
> http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This is free software: you are free
> to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent
> permitted by law. Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
> This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=avr".
> Type "show configuration" for configuration details. For bug reporting
> instructions, please see: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.
> Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
> http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/.
>
> For help, type "help". Type "apropos word" to search for commands
> related to "word"... Reading symbols from testburst.out... 0x00000000
> in __vectors () Breakpoint 1 at 0x198: file testburst.c, line 62.
> Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only
> addresses.

***At this point I get no gdb prompt, commands are not accepted.
c
n
^C
Pressing ^C I get a prompt and now gdb accepts commands.
However I do not know how got to this point and what was done to get there.

> Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt. 0x00000194 in __vector_3 ()
> at testburst.c:122 122    } (gdb)***

What is wrond?

Comment: Maybe gdb is busy trying to connect or communicate with `localhost:4242` and it got stuck.  You can put `strace` before your GDB command to show exactly what system calls GDB is doing, and looking at the last few should give a good clue about what it's doing.

Comment: You could also remove those commands from the `gdbinit` file and see if you get a GDB prompt.  Then try running the commands one at a time, so you can know which one is taking forever.

Comment: Well, I used strace to analyze what is happening. I did as follows:

run avarice: avarice -w -P attiny45 --jtag usb:24cf --mkII :4242 &

Then opened a new teminal and entered the commands below one after other.

strace avr-gdb testburst.out 2>/tmp/report
target remote localhost:4242
break main
continue

Unfortunately I have to look for an appropriate site to get help because stackoverflow comment size does not allow me to copy here the result.